# Import Error for PyMySQL on Idle Python 3.6.5

Tags: python, pip, python-3.6

I am trying to import PyMySQl in idle, but I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyshell#1", line 1, in <module>
    import PyMySQL
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyMySQL'
```

I tried to install the package from CMD by using `py -m pip install PyMySQL` and it ended with `"Successfully installed PyMySQL-0.8.1"`. Do I have to do install this PyMySQL anywhere else as to make it work in idle using `import` command?

Comment: are you entering `import pymysql`  or `import PyMySQL` ?

Comment: I entered PyMySQL. Do I have to do pymysql ? I tried now this option, it did not throw me any error. Will it work now ?

Comment: Yes try this `import pymysql.cursors`

Comment: Great ! Thank You @Avezan for your time and help !